# Using a Custom font on weebly blog

Tags: css, fonts, weebly

I'm trying to use a custom font on my blog which is I haven't make it work yet. Maybe you guys can help me out on this.

I just want my blog title to have its own font. here's the HTML structure

http://prntscr.com/curez2

First thing I did was I uploaded my ttf font in my asset folder

http://prntscr.com/cura4a

Next, import the font in CSS "main_style.css"

http://prntscr.com/curfro

here's the class on my blog-title

http://prntscr.com/curgr8

did I miss something? can someone help me out please. thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the full path to the .ttf file on http://prnt.sc/curfro

Comment: No, actually they do NOT need to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have everything right, however not seeing a live example makes it a little hard to isolate. But there are a few things to consider. For example:

1. Did you try publishing the site?
2. Are you ONLY trying the Blog Title?
3. IF you have set your Font Settings for the Title and Blog Post
   Title, to a specific font, it's going to override the Theme's design
   and your custom Font. In that case edit the Font Settings and choose
   "Default". Then try to see if it works(dont forget to publish). See: https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/201505666-Edit-Fonts
4. Is the 'Content Area' a div with an ID of content `<div id="content"></div>` (IF not that could be the issue.) Note: **#content h2.blog-title** could also be written as **.blog-post .blog-header h2.blog-title**
5. Have you tried a different font file(try a different font type/file)

With that, you should at least be able to isolate the issue, if not resolve it.